# How to password protect certain nodes in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a chat room with a Fireabse Realtime Database backend and I want some of the rooms to be password protected. I have a rough idea of how that could work but I'm having trouble fully fleshing it out. Say my structure is like this:

```
Chatrooms : {
    -randomID : {
        roomName: 'Chatroom 1',
        password: 'foobar' 
        messages: {
          ...
        }
    }
}
```

I could set up security structure as such for rooms that need a passwords:

```
'Chatrooms' : {
    -randomID : {
        'roomName': 'Chatroom 1',
        'password': 'foobar',
        '.read': "data.child('validatedUsers/*user's uid*').val() === true",
        'validatedUsers' : {
            *user's uid* : true,
            *other user's uid* : true,
            ...
        }
        'messages': {
          '.read': false
          ...
        }
    }
}
```

This way (as I understand it) I can add user's who have been granted access to the validatedUsers object and if they are in the list then the top level .read will override the 'messages' read.

My problem is I can't figure out a secure way to get the password, check it against what the user entered, and then enter them into the validatedUsers object. Since it wouldn't be secure to do so no the client would I need a cloud function of some sort to do the checks? Now that I think about it I would likely need a cloud function to hash the password anyway?

Comment: There's no password-based security in Realtime Database.  You'll have to implement something yourself.

Comment: You're kinda on the right path but forget passwords; implementing them in that fashion is insecure - i.e. one user could simply give the password to another user and then they have access. Take this example; suppose you are the chat room host and want users Bill and Ted to be able to access your chat room. As the host, you add Bill and Ted's uid to a node within your chat room node */allowed_users: bills_uid: true* and */allowed_users: teds_uid: true*. When Bill tries to access the chatroom, the Firebase Rules would verify that bills uid exists within your chatrooms */allowed_users* node.

Comment: @Jay Thanks for the ideas that makes sense, I think it would be acceptable to create a “request access” and “approve access” feature where the request passes the uid to the host and the hosts approval adds it to the list. I’ll leave this open though in case someone has a creative way to use passwords since the original use case was for a venue to be able to post “Room/Password” so guests could access it, potentially to the scale that it would be tedious to individually approve, but as you say that would be less secure anyway.